# gitlab-runner GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS

Tags: gitlab

I have an older version of gitlab-runner  (gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601)).  I am trying to force HTTPS usage for submodule cloning.  In my gitlab-ci.yml file I have a couple variable lines that look like the following.  In the log at the very bottom, it looks like gitlab-runner is still using SSH.  Is there a bug in 11.10.1 that doesn't honor the GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS setting?

```
variables:
    GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CI_CONCURRENT_ID/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
    GIT_DEPTH: 1
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    CI_PROJECT: ""
    CI_COLLECT_COVERAGE: 0
    CI_WHO_LIST: ""
    CI_TESTLIST: regress_full_list
    GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
```

When my pipeline runs, I see this in the log:

```
Cloning into '/scratch01/fpga_ci7/builds/0/fpga/prime/topsim'...
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@gitXXX.XXXXX.com:fpga/topsim.git' into submodule path '/scratch01/fpga_ci7/builds/0/fpga/prime/topsim' failed
Failed to clone 'topsim'. Retry scheduled
```

Comment: You'd have much better luck reporting it as a (potential) issue here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/?sort=created_date&state=opened&search=GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS&first_page_size=20

Comment: After updating to 16.2.1 the issue has resolved itself.

Comment: Well, please post it as an answer in that case, but not sure how useful "I forgot to upgrade my software" kind of question is in general. Ensuring software is up-to-date should be few steps before posting a question here.